# How to set hadoop cluster priority?

Tags: hadoop, configuration

I am starting to learn Hadoop. I have a hadoop server and it connects with 3 clusters node. If I run a MapReduce job it works well. I need to set the priority for these clusters.

For example

node1, node2, node3 are my cluster which is connect with my hadoop server. Here If I run the MR job, It will split and assign job like the above priority for every time. Is it possible?

Because the cluster nodes have different memory capacity. So I need to set high memory node will handle the Job first.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to 'weight' certain servers based on capacity.  However, each server can have a configuration to match it's memory, processor count, etc.

For example, if one server has 16 cores and another has 8 cores, you can configure the first server to run 12 tasks simultaneously and the second to only run 6.  The same idea with memory.